# Dinamically repeat HTML section

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a page from my company's website which includes a code snippet from our external HR platform that renders all the job vacancies we currently have available. Since we weren't happy with default look and feel of what that snippet was rendering, I've grabbed some if its elements' content through JS and created an entirely new structure using said content.

I now have an additional challenge I'm not being able to overcome: I'd need the part of the HTML where that content is being injected to be repeated dynamically as many times as the number of job vacancies available at any given moment - an info that's provided from the external code snippet and that, naturally, keeps changing constantly.

Can anyone help me achieve this? Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="positions">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="section-listing">
     <div id="BambooHR" data-domain="xxx.bamboohr.com" data-version="1.0.0" data-departmentId="" style="display:none;"></div>
     <script src="https://xxx.bamboohr.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
     <div class="job-opp">
       <div class="job-main-content">
         <p class="job-title"></p>
         <div class="job-details">
           <div class="department-location">
             <p class="job-department"></p>
             <span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;</span>
             <p class="job-location"></p>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button button-secondary">
          <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <span class="text">Apply</span>
            <span class="icon">
              <Icon name="cta-arrow-right" size="16" />
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

window.addEventListener("load", function() {


  setTimeout(function() {
    const mappings = [
      {
        sourceSelector: '.BambooHR-ATS-Jobs-Item a',
        targetSelector: '.job-title',
      },
      {
        sourceSelector: '.BambooHR-ATS-Location',
        targetSelector: '.job-location',
      },
      {
        sourceSelector: '.BambooHR-ATS-Department-Header',
        targetSelector: '.job-department',
      },
      {
        sourceSelector: '.BambooHR-ATS-Jobs-Item a',
        targetSelector: '.button-secondary a',
      },
    ];

    mappings.forEach((mapping) => {
      const sourceElements = document.querySelectorAll(mapping.sourceSelector);
      const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll(mapping.targetSelector);

      sourceElements.forEach((sourceElement, index) => {
        if (index < targetElements.length) {
          if (mapping.targetSelector === '.button-secondary a') {
            targetElements[index].href = sourceElement.href;
          } else {
            targetElements[index].textContent = sourceElement.textContent;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }, 1000);
});

</script>
```

For clarity sake, I'm specifying below which parts of my code are 1) the external script and 2) the HTML section that I'd need to be repeated as many times as the number of job vacancies.

**External script**

```
<div id="BambooHR" data-domain="xxx.bamboohr.com" data-version="1.0.0" data-departmentId="" style="display:none;"></div>
<script src="https://xxx.bamboohr.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
```

**HTML to be repeated**

```
<div class="job-opp">
  <div class="job-main-content">
    <p class="job-title"></p>
    <div class="job-details">
      <div class="department-location">
        <p class="job-department"></p>
        <span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;</span>
        <p class="job-location"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="button button-secondary">
     <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
       <span class="text">Apply</span>
       <span class="icon">
         <Icon name="cta-arrow-right" size="16" />
       </span>
     </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to create HTML snippets dynamically using JS? If yes, did you check createElement method of JS?

Comment: You should probably implement your new HTML structure as a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element. Then you loop over your input data, clone the template each time, populate the relevant fields inside of the clone, and append the clone to the document.

Comment: Thank @CBroe for your suggestion. I'm afraid what you're suggesting is beyond my scope of knowledge, would you be able to provide more info regarding the code I'd need to write in order to achieve my objective? Thank you once again!

Comment: Can't tell what the original HTML the script produces is right now, I'm assuming that's because with `xxx.bamboohr.com` you used a fake example parameter? But you should rather loop over whatever the grouping element for one job offer is, than over the _parts_ of a job offer as you currently seems to be doing.

Comment: @CBroe, each job offer is grouped under an <li> with class `.BambooHR-ATS-Department-Item`. Would you mind further explaining through an answer how you'd modify the code in order to achieve what I'm attempting? Thank you!

Comment: You should loop over those `li` then - each of those is what you want to create _one_ of your new HTML output structures for. Inside the loop, clone the template. You can still use your `mappings` array now - you use `querySelector` _on_ the current `li` element, to find the source field in there, and the same way you find the target element inside your clone of the template. After you iterated over your mappings, you append the clone to the document.